# If a <li> is clicked, hide the inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My DOM looks like this:

```
<li id="li1">
         <div class="c1"></div>
</li>
<li id="li2">
         <div class="c1"></div>
</li>
```

Using jQuery, if the first `<li>` is clicked, I want the inner `<div></div>` to be hidden.

Answer (score 8):

```
$("li:first").click(function() {
    $(this).children("div").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You will run into problems when ID'ing 2 list items as the same ID. If you want the same CSS to apply to both, use classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

this might work for you:

note: make sure you include the jquery.js, i was lazy and didnt put it in here.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".clickableLI").click(function(){
        $(this).find("div").hide();    
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="clickableLI">
             <div class="c1"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="clickableLI">
             <div class="c1"></div>
        </li>
    <ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having two identical IDs is invalid xHTML

Not sure about the exact jQuery syntax

but in sudo code would be something like:

li1 addEvent('click')

{
    
get child of li1, filter by class c1
    
set style on child(display, none) 

}